# Using "it's" vs. using "it is" at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction “it's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its)

Why is it that the following sounds incorrect:

> "Would she know where it's?"

But this sounds fine:

> "Would she know where it is?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't contract away a stressed syllable.  It's counter to the very nature of contraction.

See also the answer to [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction "It's"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its)