# Is there a rule for when contractions are not possible?

Tags: contractions, word-formation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction “it's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its)

In conversing with non-native English speakers online, I saw someone type:

> Do you know who ****I’m*** ?

This is obviously wrong to a native English speaker, but I don’t know why.  Is there a rule that tells when contractions are not allowed?

Here are some more similar examples where the contraction doesn’t work (with the expansion of the contraction in parentheses following each):

- Can you tell who **I’m* by my voice alone?  (I am)
- Please, tell me who **he’s/she’s/they’re*. (he is/she is/they are)
- If you want to go to the movie, **we’ll.*  (we will)
- Will you have some? Yes, **I’ll.* (I will)
- I won’t have any, but tell me if **you’ll*. (you will)
- I didn’t have the same thing for supper as **you’d.* (you had)
- Would you like to go?  Sure **I’d.*  (I would)

Comment: Thanks to @tchrist, Cerberus, JasperLoy for help coming up with more examples.

Comment: This is a fascinating question. I'll take a stab: You can't contract an uncomplemented verb.

Comment: This question has a few more examples, but they are covering the same basic phenomenon.

Answer (score 4):

All OP's examples are cases where the verb is *stressed*. In many/most contexts, this applies where the verb *ends the statement* (#1 can be recast as *Can you tell by my voice alone who I am?*).

The most general "rule" I can think of is *don't contract anything unless you hear native speakers doing it*. Also bear in mind that contractions primarily reflect *spoken usage*, but many aspects of speech aren't necessarily reflected in written usage anyway. So perhaps the second "rule" should be *don't **write** a contracted form unless you see native speakers using that written form.*

Comment: No stress was intended.

Comment: @Spare Oom: Whether you "intend" it or not, single-syllable verb forms are invariably stressed unless they're acting as auxiliary/modal components alongside another more significant verb. One (slightly contrived) example contradicting that is when you meet someone you know who's accompanied by someone you *don't* know. Some (but not many) speakers might say "Hello, John!" to the person they already know, then turn to the other and say *"And you're?"*. But most speakers wouldn't contract there anyway - they'd say *"And you **are**?"* (stressed verb form).

Comment: Where is the stress in the two-word sentence “I’m sure” then?  I find it to fall customarily on the second word, not the first.

Comment: tchrist, funny you choose this phrase, because it's an excellent example.  In this case, choosing the contracted form "I'm" actually changes the nuance of the sentence:  The stress for "I'm sure" is the second word, "sure".  The message is the **choice** of the word *sure*:  the **best word**, the **word that I have chosen** to describe what I AM is:  "Sure."  If I spell out the contraction, "I am sure" the message changes ever so slightly.  Here the word sure is a given, but what I'm stressing is the state of the sureness:  I AM sure.  I'm affirming that I really AM sure.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd stress your example like this: _"Hello John!"_ turning to second person: _"And **you** are?"_ The way you've stressed it would be a possible response to _"You're not the Pope"_: _"And you **are**?"_

Answer (score -3):

You can use contractions when:

It is a subject + auxiliary. (He's, they're)

A negative with not. (Isn't, didn't)

A wh- with is. (Who's, where's)

'Will' is little different as it can be contracted withe a subject pronoun (she'll) or a wh- (who'll).

Comment: That doesn't explain why *"I'm not a lawyer, but he's" and *"I'm not a lawyer; who's?" are wrong.

Comment: Yes it does. In both of those, the 'is' is a main verb, so it should not be contracted.