# Is there an exception to the prohibition against ending a sentence with “ ’s ” at work here?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, contractions, sentence-ends

The *’s* can be used as a contraction representing a weak, unstressed word that is not pronounced.  It allegedly cannot occur in sentence final position.

> - She is not ready, but he is.
> - She’s not ready, but he is.
> - She’s not ready, but ***he’s**.

The last one is not grammatical there.

Similarly, here the last one is not grammatical:

> - He has not started yet, but she has.
> - He’s not started yet, but she has.
> - He’s not started yet, but ***she’s**.

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2547) claims this is because you cannot end a sentence with a weak form.  It backs up its point with reasonably scholarly documentation.

However, this does not seem to be invariably true.

> - Shall we go to the movies?  Yes, let us go.
> - Shall we go to the movies?  Yes, let’s go.
> - Shall we go to the movies?  Yes, **let’s**.

Unlike the third example in the first two sets, here in this case the third example is indeed grammatical, despite ending with a weak form.

Is this an exception to the rule, or is there another rule at work here?

Comment: Isn't "let's" the goofy contraction? I wouldn't be surprised if "let's" *is* the stronger form. :P

Comment: Doesn’t the rule say that the weak forms of _is_ and _has_ may not occur in final position, rather than that _’s_ may not do so?

Comment: I seem to remember that ***let's*** is an example of [grammaticalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammaticalization), but I don't think that applies to ***he's, she's*** etc. Apart from anything else, the contracted part in ***let's*** is the all-important pronoun ***us*** (which has true *meaning* in context), whereas in the others it's just an almost superfluous ***is*** (simply a "helper verb" required by grammatical considerations).

Comment: I think the correct formulation of the rule is: you can't contract *is*, *are*, *has*, *had*, or *have* at the end of of a sentence.

Comment: @PeterShor Maybe that, but if so, it’s also something else. You can’t have *I will => I’ll* or *She would => she’ll* at the end, either.

Comment: @Peter,tchrist: It seems to me rule is more like *you can't contract **auxiliary verbs** at the end of a sentence.* But if indeed the permissible forms (as opposed to the *unacceptable* ones) can be fully defined by "rules", it's not obvious to me why we only accept *My cellmate said, "Let's have a party tonight". But the prison guards wouldn't let us*. Where expanding the first instance would be hopelessly archaic, and contracting the second would be a complete no-no.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126774/shortest-correct-sentence-in-english-use-of-contractions/126839#126839), which somewhat incidentally also answers this question: a sentence whose predicate consists only of a verb must have sentential stress on the verb, and stressed units cannot be syncopated away. In “Let's!”, the stressed unit (the verb) is intact, while the non-predicative part of the sentence (which does not have to bear stress) is unstressed and therefore able to be syncopated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Will you think of exceptions?" "I should've."

Comment: @jejorda2: I suppose you could get away with, say, ***He** shouldn't have married her! **I** should've!* But it feels a little awkward to me, and it's partly licensed by the fact of ***should*** being repeated. Compare that with *He didn't marry her, but he should've*, where although as a Cockney I'd still be likely to drop the /h/, I'd probably retain the full vowel as per ***should 'ave*** rather than reducing it to a neutral schwa. But these aren't the kind of usages OP is asking about here.

Comment: I think your interesting example shows that "let's" is not a contraction.

Answer (score 9):

It's worth noting that they're contracting different things:
He's/She's = He is/She is (not he has/she has, as you use it in the second set of examples)
Let's = let us.

So "he's" is a contraction of the form N+V while "let's" is V+N.

Other N+V contractions can't end sentences:"
"Is there a dog here?" "*Yes, there's"
"Is that a mammoth?" "*Yes, it's"
"Will you take me to the store?" "Yes, I'll"
"Are you santa?" "Yes, I'm"

But contractions with the verb first, you can:
"Should I jump over this alligator?" "No, don't!"
"Will you go to the moon with me?" "No, I won't"

And possessive 's can also end sentences:
"Why is that cat staring at me?" "Don't worry man, it's Tom's"

So it seems like the only contractions that can't come at the end of a sentence are those which the contracted portion is a verb!

Hope that helps!

Comment: I think you’re onto something, but I think it only involves auxiliary verbs, whether modal or otherwise.

Comment: Totally. I can't think of a contraction that uses a non auxilliary verb actually.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic expressions "let us . . ." / "let's . . ."

meaning roughly

"here's an idea; I strongly suggest that we . . ."

are, I think, always interchangeable on grammatical grounds (though some older Church leaders might consider "Let's pray" over-informal, and often sentences like "Let us go to the cinema tonight" would sound far too stilted).

However, "let us . . ." meaning "allow us to" is never rendered "let's". Idioms often seem to have their own rules.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, I'm sorry. (I was doing some googling about this and couldn't find anyone who'd written out the whole rule, so let's try this.)

**Contractions of the form *xyz + to be* (in that order) only appear with a predicative expression following.**

You can look up what a [predicative expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression) is, but here's some examples:

- He's {ready}.
- She's {a firefighter}.
- They're {at home}.
- That's {great}.

You can think of the predicative expression as the supplement to the verb *to be*.

The uncontracted form is always possible, the contracted one isn't. When there's no predicative expression following, you don't contract:

- That's {how it is {}}.
- Now's {the time to party}, right? -- Wait a second.. Now is {}.

**That's not restricted to the end of a sentence:**

- **I don't know where he is {} all the time.**

*all the time* is not the predicative expression here, that role goes to *where*. In contrast, we have:

- He's {where exactly}?
- I don't know where he's {going} all the time.
- I don't know why he's {grumpy}.
- I don't know why he's {leaving}.
- That's {all the time we've got in our show today}.

Analogous rules work for contractions with *will, would, have, had*.