# what comes after "The problem is ..."?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive, bare-infinitive

What comes after "the problem is...."? to infinitive or bare infinitive or gerund?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The problem is he is stingy"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192860/the-problem-is-he-is-stingy) Kolln advises the use of a comma say after such an introductory element; a **main (independent) clause** follows. Alternatively, 'The problem is the defective manifold / icing on the wings' shows an alternative construction, with 'The problem is' **not** an introductory element.

Comment: I cannot see that the link is a duplicate.

Comment: I voted to close, but not as a duplicate.

Comment: What ***very often*** comes after ***The problem is...*** is repetition of the verb, followed by a "relativiser": [*The problem **is is** that...*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+problem+is+is+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThe%20problem%20is%20is%20that%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 0):

> What comes after "the problem is...."?

A statement of the nature of the problem:

The problem is difficult;
The problem is solved;
The problem is solved by John;
The problem is the error;
The problem is to correct the error;
The problem is reducing;
The problem is reducing the water flow;
The problem is the reducing of the water flow;
The problem is the reduction of the water flow;
The problem is that we have no tools;
The problem is not the dependence on his parents

Comment: can i say the problem is correct the error? and to be is do instead of to be is to do?

Comment: No. "The problem is **to** correct the error."