# "If you don't do it, I'll". Why does that sentence feel so awkward?

Tags: contractions, sentence-ends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction “it’s”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its)

Earlier today while writing a very informal email, I expressed:

> If you don't do it, I will.

Upon looking at it, I realized that "I will" could be contracted to "I'll", however, this is completely unheard of and feels quite awkward.  I am now quite curious, is there a reason why ending a sentence with "I'll" feels (or is) so inappropriate?

I understand that the use of contractions is generally an informal use of language so rules of usage can be a bit loose. Therefore, this is a case that to me doesn't make logical sense and  I'm a bit confused.  Why does it feel wrong when an "I'll" is placed at at that end of a sentence, even though such an expression is informal and not, technically, an incorrect usage of the contraction "I'll?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contractions can only be used in English when the thing they're contracting does not have any sentence-level stress. (Sentences have stress in them much like words do.) In this sentence, the word *I* carries a heavy stress:

> If she doesn't do it, **I** will.

Because of this, *I* cannot contract with any of its neighbors. The same thing explains why we don't use contractions in sentences of the following sort:

> Do **not** go in there.
>
> I **would** go to the store, but I have to study.

Comment: I get it.  That makes perfect sense, however, "Don't go in there." doesn't at all *feel* incorrect.  This is probably because I was born and raised in the South-East US where if you can contract it, you should at least try to. ;)

Comment: I don't think that this has anything to do with sentence stress, just the stress patterns in the sentences in the answer. "**Don't** go in there" means exactly the same thing as "Do **not** go in there": stress is on the negative. And "**I'd** go to the store, but..." means the same thing as "I **would** go..., but...", but the stress is on "I" more than on "would" in the contracted form, so the sentence is responding to a different complaint: "Why do **I** have to go?" instead of "Why **don't** you go to the store (now)?"

Comment: @BillFranke Actually your second example suggests that this answer isn't quite right.  In the case of "**I'd** go...", you can indeed stress the contraction *I'd* and get emphasis on the "I".  So why doesn't that apply to *I'll*?  Well, it does at the beginning of a sentence ("**I'll** go...").  So it looks like it's really to do with sentence location that causes the problem, not the contraction.

Comment: @Jez: It has to do with the contraction being at the end of the sentence. The stress can be anywhere in the sentence and it's still wrong to say "... but I'll." You can also stress the "I" in the sentence-final "I'll" and it's still wrong because it's at the end of the sentence. OTOH, I just found an answer to this Q on another site that says we can end sentences with contractions as long as the verb isn't the modal aux "will": eg, _He does it, but I don't_. =  _He does it, but I don't (do it)_. There's probably more to it.

Comment: @BillFranke  You can't contract *have* or *be* terminally either. I think the rule is you have to have a formally complete verb, even if it's only an auxiliary; a contracted verb in any position demands completion to the right.

Comment: @StoneyB: "He has, but I **haven't**" seems fine to me. "He isn't, but **I'm**" is impossible.

Comment: @BillFranke  My point is that in **haven't**, **don't** and the like you've got a complete verb, not a contracted one - what's contracted is the *not*.

Comment: I think that it is indeed a matter of stress. The "bad" form in the question isn't technically incorrect, but it's weak. And the reason the sentence is weak, is that the contraction weakens a vital part of it - what the speaker will do. One of the advantages of contractions is they weaken less important parts of a sentence, but that is precisely why it's poor here.

Comment: @BillFranke: So, you **wouldn't** say, _"He isn't, but I'm"_? Perhaps **you** wouldn't, but **I'd**. (just kidding, of course; I'd not say either of those, except to provide another example)

Comment: @StoneyB: Okay, I see what you mean now. "He hasn't been to Paris, but **I've**" is no good: It has to be "**I have**". Right. That's why I said there's got to be more to it than I said in my now-deleted answer and some comments. I just don't have time right now to do the necessary research. Usage isn't the problem here, but the specifics of the grammar are. I haven't unpacked my Quirk, Greenbaum, et al. yet, and I've been living here for more than 8 months.

Comment: @J.R.: I couldn't say it, but I might write it, just for kicks.