# Using "it's" instead of "it is"

Tags: contractions

I like the way contractions operate and I know the difference between "it's" and "its" based on contraction and possession. That is, "it's = it is" and "its" is possessive.

However, there are some sentences when I feel justified in replacing "it is" with its contraction, but for some reason it doesn't sound right nor does it read correctly to me:

> The method won't be approved because of how difficult it is to implement.

compared to

> The method won't be approved because of how difficult it's to implement.

Is this a correct (or uncommon) usage of the contraction "it's"? Why does it sound awkward when spoken?

Comment: Take a look how Google's book scans [How difficult it's](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22how+difficult+it%27s%22&gws_rd=ssl) or [How difficult it's to](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22how+difficult+it%27s%22&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22how+difficult+it%27s+to%22). It's not necessarily *common*, but it's in use and not necessarily incorrect. (Comment is not an answer, but a hint to help provide research for (a better?) question)

Comment: Contractions are best left for informal and vernacular speech. Your example sounds rather officious. Words like *"approved"* and *"implement"* don't fit well with contractions and perhaps this is why it's sounding a bit off. See what I did there?

Comment: @Martin Krzywinski Yes. You gave a different example. OP's doesn't sound wonderful in **any** register.

Comment: Addressed (by CGEL via nohat) at [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction "it's"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its).

Comment: @SrJoven: There are over 5000 Google results for *"how difficult it's"* but only 15 results for *"how difficult it's to"*. You can get 15 Google books hits for lots of completely ungrammatical sentences.

Comment: @PeterShor in which way would it be ungrammatical versus simply off to the ear? There's no particular rule that it violates.

Comment: @SrJoven: It violates the same grammatical rule as contracting *"That's what it is."* to *"That's what it's.*" See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its) for more details.

Comment: I think you generally can't contract `is` or `are` before an infinitive, only before a noun, gerund, or adjective.

Comment: @PeterShor Ending in contraction violates a specific part that is addressed. It's not enough to say look at the no-scaffolding rule and apply it to this.

Comment: @SrJoven: Did you read the accepted answer to the question I linked to? It doesn't mention a *"no-scaffolding"* rule. It says (quoting *the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*) that you can't contract a verb if the object is *preposed*, that is, it comes before the verb. Here, the object is *difficult* and it comes before the verb.

Comment: @PeterShor I saw *stranded/stranding* earlier in the day, forgot what word I saw, and added *no-scaffolding* to compensate for the mental block on that word. I want to make sure I understand your statement about "the object is *difficult*." Are you using *is* as a condition of being or a state of equality? Wouldn't difficult be an [object complement](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/objects.htm)?

Comment: @SrJoven: You're right; *"difficult"* is not an object but a subject complement. But the rule that you can't contract it because the complement is preposed still holds. You can't say *"see how difficult it's"*, *"See how difficult to implement it's"*, or *"See how difficult it's to implement"*. You have to use *"it is"* in all three cases.