# Does I'll replace I will?

Tags: grammar

I can say "I will go", or "I'll go", and the both mean the same thing.

However, if you ask me "Can you go?", can I respond with "I'll" instead of "I will"?

Comment: Also related: [Technically, would the contraction “I'm” be a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264788/technically-would-the-contraction-im-be-a-sentence)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is completely fine.

*I'll go* sounds as plausible as *I will go* if someone asks you that.

**EDIT:**
NO, it is incorrect if you're merely answering with "I'll". "I'll" can never be used alone.

Sorry, I got confused.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking if merely "I'll" is correct usage

Comment: No, it is not correct usage!

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. Then no, it is incorrect if you're merely answering with "I'll". "I'll" can never be used alone.

Comment: @Alan, you should probably edit your answer to give people a chance to reverse their downvotes.