# Sentence-final contractions

Tags: contractions, sentence-ends, contraction-vs-full-form

There are some pieces of inflection like the genitive marker that can attach to phrases (cf. [*The man in the hall*]*’s taste in wallpaper is appalling*) and so they sometimes behave like a contraction. They can also be sentence-final:

> (1) Chomsky's book was boring and so was Lasnik's

So I was wondering whether you could have a more or less natural sentence-final contracted auxiliary (widely believed to be impossible). Specifically, I want to know if (2) or (3) are natural-sounding when they express something like (4). (I indicate strong stress with capitalization.)

> (2) It's not CHOMSKY that's leaving but LASNIK'S
>
> (3) It's not CHOMSKY who's leaving but LASNIK'S
>
> (4) Rather than CHOMSKY leaving, LASNIK is leaving

Comment: I can live with these versions, only: (2) It's not CHOMSKY that's leaving, but LASNIK. (3) It's not CHOMSKY who's leaving. but LASNIK. (4) Rather than CHOMSKY leaving, LASNIK is.

Comment: Is this any different from [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction "it's"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/500/191178)?

Comment: [*There is a rule -- or a set of rules -- that effectively forbids subject-auxiliary contractions at the end of a sentence.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277537/contractions-in-odd-places#comment613934_277537) Auxiliaries, to be contracted or deleted, must be followed by their main verb; if that has been deleted (by, for example, conjunction reduction, as here), then contraction can't occur.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["If you don't do it, I'll". Why does that sentence feel so awkward?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94940/if-you-dont-do-it-ill-why-does-that-sentence-feel-so-awkward) Or [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction _it's_?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its)? // (1) is fine, using the Saxon genitive, but (2) and (3) use the contraction _'s_ for _is_, and this is barred in sentence-terminal position (similarly _I'm_, _we're_, _you'd_ ...).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the infamous apostrophe S.  Yes, you'll see it in some contractions, but it's also used to show possession, for example, "Those aren't my dirty dishes, they're Tom's."  (If this were a contraction, that would mean it's short for "Tom is.")

When you speak of Lasnik's book being boring, that's the possessive, not a contraction.  (The book that Lasnik wrote, or as it's expressed in some languages, the book of Lasnik.)

Your other sentences do involve a contraction.  If we allow repetition, #3 would be  "It's not Chomsky who's leaving, [but rather] it's Lasnik who's leaving." (Note that "who" is preferred over "that," because Lasnik is a person.)

With the type of sentence you are working on, we need a parallel construction.  *It's [not] Chomsky => it's Lasnik.*

All that leads us to the following corrections to your proposed sentences 2 through 4:

> (2) It's not Chomsky that's leaving, but Lasnik.
>
> (3) It's not Chomsky who's leaving, but Lasnik.
>
> (4) Rather than Chomsky leaving, Lasnik is.

Note that in #4, we need the "is," because there is no other instance of that word in the sentence.

Your #1 is fine.