# "You're as [ADJECTIVE] as you are [ADJECTIVE]" construction: why does it sound awkward when you replace "you are" with "you're"?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, contractions, phonetics, stress

I'm just wondering what it is about this construction that makes it sound "incorrect" even though technically it is grammatically correct. Is it an awkwardness arising from a lack of cadence, or rhythm of the sentence? Is it a case of rhetorical anaphora* just evolving to be more popular rather than rhetorical repetition? I'm wondering if the popularization of this construct is more due to chance than to any underlying logic.

> *anaphora ([OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/anaphora)): *Grammar* ~ The use of a word referring to or replacing a word used earlier in a sentence, to avoid repetition, such as *do* in *I like it and so do they*.

---

[Google Ngrams: " * as you are ADJECTIVE "](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+as+you+are+beautiful&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgood%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwise%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bintelligent%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bkind%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmart%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhearted%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bclever%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bnoble%20as%20you%20are%20beautiful%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

---

[Google Ngrams: " * as you're ADJECTIVE "](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+as+you%27re+beautiful&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=) (no results)

---

Comment: That second you're will sound like your when spoken. People might expect a noun, and get an adjective tossed at them instead.

Comment: @Wayfaring Stranger ~ that's a good point. I pronounce "your" more like "or" but I suppose other dialects pronounce "your and you're" similarily

Comment: Weak forms (contractions) don't work in some contexts. Compare *'She's not as beautiful as you're.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's different, though, because there's not complement there and the contraction ends up being all there is in the sentence—that's a grammatical/syntactical restriction. In the case given here, there really is no grammatical reason for it not to be correct.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet The grammatical/syntactical restriction is essentially merely reflecting what people usually do. There's no grammar czar. You could argue that interchanging 'you are' and 'you're' _in all situations_ is exactly as logical as interchanging 'Information Technology' and 'IT'. Many Brits use 'He's a nice new car now' quite happily, whereas others might deem it 'ungrammatical' (because they don't use it). I'm convinced that acceptable stress patterns in speech, rather than some weird quintessential natural grammar, drive acceptability.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My point was that a clause like “It’s.” is ungrammatical in every context in every variety of English, for various well-understood and reasonably simple reasons. A clause like “It's crazy” is (as far as I know) not ungrammatical in **any** context in any variety of English—except this particular saying (and even there only when the subject is the same as in the preceding clause). Saying it’s ungrammatical because people don't use it is basically negating the existence of linguistics, which seems rather defeatist.

Comment: What is the 'grammatical reason' for 'She's not as beautiful as you're.' not being acceptable? 'You can't end a sentence with some contractions' is an observed rule, not a reason. I'm saying that the underlying reason (after all, 'She's not as beautiful as you're.' would be unambiguous and clear) is more accurate reflection of the spoken form. See nohat's answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its). Thus the example I add is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the "as ... as" construction has a deleted part which follows "are", words preceding deleted constituents must bear stress, and stressed words cannot be contracted.

"You're as (to an extent) wise, as you are (to that extent) well-traveled" has the elision of "to that extent".  This causes "are" to be stressed and prevents it being contracted to "'re" by deletion of the stressed vowel.

Comment: I'm surprised this got accepted as an answer so quick. It might be plausible, but I think you should do more to try to argue that there's elided material and not some other reason the contraction is blocked.

Comment: @Silenus, "some other reason"?  For instance?

Comment: Well, I guess I was thinking "want to" can't be contracted into "wanna" in some constructions because of the presence of a covert syntactic element between "want" and "to." This differs from your explanation since yours has the elided material coming after the construction, which forces a stress, which in turn blocks contraction. But maybe on some syntactic analyses of the OP's construction there's a covert element *between* the "you" and the "are", rather than (possibly) covert elided material *after* it (not everybody treats ellipsis as involving covert elements).

Comment: I like your answer though. Could you point to a source which makes the claim that elided material forces a stress and that stresses prevent contraction. Just curious for my own education...

Comment: There is a more natural account which appeals to the Nuclear Stress rule of SPE to explain the stress which prevents the contraction.  I started writing that out as an answer, but the constituent structure I was forced to assume got so complicated, I gave up on it.  A source?  Well, I don't know one off-hand.  I recall hearing a talk about it back in the 80's by Derek Bickerton -- it was a hot topic back then due to talk about traces emanating from the MIT school.

Comment: If this is truly the reason, then why does a contracted subject-verb work fine when the subjects are different? “He's as sad as I'm angry” is fine, but “He's as sad as *he’s angry” isn't (unless they're different _he_’s)… but surely if there's a trace of a deleted element in one, there ought to be one in both, oughtn’t there?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet  The 'unless they're different _he_'s' surely shows why. In speech, the 'different' he is stressed, whereas '_is_ angry' is stressed with the 'same' he.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I can't get *_He's as sad as I'm angry._ I'd hafta stress _I am_ and couldn't contract it. I'm not sure I'd state the generalization the same way as Greg, but it's the right generalization and covers most kinds of deletions, to the point where exceptions would be very interesting.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I'm not very happy with any of the accounts mentioned here.  I have the feeling they all miss the point, which is that it's fundamentally a rhythmic phenomenon.  Say your two examples over and feel the difference in rhythm:  HE's as, SAD as I'm, ANGry versus HE's as, SAD as, HE's __, ANGry.  The silences can carry beats, too, but it's hard to show in a transcription.