# Would it be grammatically correct to say "You're" instead of "You are"?

Tags: word-usage

Example: If someone says they're wrong and they're right, so someone corrects them, telling them they're right, they deny it again, can you say "You're" instead of "You are"

Comment: ... but the original (and the best general answer) is at [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction it's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its).

Answer (score -3):

If you say only "You're." (which sounds just like "your"), you'll be replied to with "My what?".

There are no contractions in English, spoken or written, when the only two words in a sentence are a pronoun and a verb ("You are.", "I am.", "He is." etc.).

Comment: Hello, 244. Please have a look at the standard of nohat's answer in the thread linked to above. But not my downvote.