# When is "Your" grammatically correct instead of "You are"

Tags: grammaticality

So a while ago, I [edited an answer on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/357593/revisions), wondering ***Your*** should be replaced with ***You are***. Here is an excerpt from the post:

> **You are** [Your] not being able to cast another close vote is also officially by design. We only let users vote to close once, whether the question is successfully closed or not. In this particular case, it might be useful for the vote to be cleared in such a way as if it had never existed at all, thus allowing you to vote to close again for a different reason........

It was later revised stating, **"Your" is grammatically correct there**. I believe he might be right as he is a moderator. Though I would want to know the reason behind it.

I've been googling for a while now and followed these posts:

- [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction “it's”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its)
- [Is it okay to say “Yes you're.” instead of “Yes you are.”? [duplicate]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51499/is-it-okay-to-say-yes-youre-instead-of-yes-you-are)
- [Would it be grammatically correct to say “You're” instead of “You are”? [duplicate]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397350/would-it-be-grammatically-correct-to-say-youre-instead-of-you-are)

But still don't know how come this is grammatically correct?

Comment: Don't forget that *your* (which is a possessive pronoun) is not the same as *you're* (which is a contraction of *you are*).

Comment: So basically, 'your' demonstrates ownership in this particular case, thus it is grammatically fit. Am I right?.

Comment: I've found a question which explains the difference.

Comment: @o_O Yes, he refers to the user's ownership of an inability to do something, and then describes it immediately afterwards with "... is also officially by design".

Comment: @AndrewLeach I really didn't knew anything about `Gerund` & `genitive`. Learnt something new today at the expense of a duplicate question :D. Thanks.

Comment: @o_O There's nothing wrong with a duplicate question, especially if you don't know the grammatical terms to search on, and your question title here is a useful pointer.