# What word could I use for a person with similar interests?

Tags: synonyms

I need to make the following sentence smaller using least words but having exact meaning.

> In Search of someone with same interests? If You're, Let's Chat

For that I was thinking to replace **"with same interests"** with a single word. I could use **"someone similar"**, **"someone common"** or **"someone alike"**. Could any of this word describe a person who has same interests? If no, then please suggest some more

Comment: *with same interest*? is romance involved? do you need adjective? I think you can make your sentence even shorter than that, like *in search of your soulmate/match/kindred spirit*.

Comment: FWIW, the contraction "you're" sounds very odd there, better to leave it as "you are". See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person *with similar interests* is a ***like-minded*** person.

ODO:

> **[like-minded](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/like-minded)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>   Having similar tastes or opinions.
>
> ‘a small group of like-minded friends’
>
> ‘Their interests are used to help define themselves and engage in
>   social scenes with like-minded people.’

MW Learner's Dictionary:

> **[like–minded](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/like-minded)**  *adjective*
>
> : having similar opinions and interests
>
> He joined a local activists' group, hoping to meet like-minded people.
>   [=people who shared his opinions]

Answer (score 1):

[**kindred spirit**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/kindred-spirit?s=t): a person whose interests or attitudes are similar to one's own.

You could also say that they had an [**affinity**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/affinity): adjective; of or relating to persons who share the same interests

[Dictionary.com]

Answer (score 1):

I think the word that you're looking for is coterie. It is a small group of people with similar interests.

> **Coterie (noun):** a small group of people with shared interests, often one that does not want other people to join them.
>
> Example: a coterie of writers.
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://www.dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/coterie)

Comment: The question is asking for a word to describe a person rather than a group.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "someone alike" or else use "compatible"

So the sentence can be:

"In search of someone alike" or

"In search of someone compatible"

Answer (score 0):

They would be your **cohort**.

What does cohort mean?
*cohort* \KOH-hort\ noun.
1 : companion, colleague.
2 a : band, group.