# When not to use a contraction for "it's"

Tags: contractions

> It's not as important as it's in this other instance.

I'm pretty sure that's wrong and that last "it's" should be "it is". My question is: why? What's the rule?

Comment: You want to emphasize the second *is*, so burying it in the contraction *is* a mistake.

Comment: This is answered by [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction "it's"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2547/191178)

Comment: (Of course, since the pronoun and verb are the same, you could just omit the second "it's" entirely—"It's not as important in this instance as in this other."

Comment: _It is_ can be contracted when _is_ functions as an unstressed auxiliary verb, which it normally does. However, when the verb phrase following _it is_ (or any other contractible pronoun+auxiliary, for that matter) has been deleted by some rule, leaving the auxiliary final in its clause, it will be stressed, and therefore won't contract.